# imported apiService undefined in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, nuxt.js, webpack-4

We are using typescript and exporting one class as following (we are using nuxt and class style component if this relates to webpack issue).

```
export class ApiService {
  static apiHost = '/';
}
```

When we try to import it as following, it gives `ApiService` as `undefined` and so gives error on `apiHost` access as `ApiService` gets `undefined`.

`import { ApiService } from '../services/api-service';`

my tsconfig is as following.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noLib": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "skipLibCheck": true, // TODO: Remove. Temporary. https://github.com/nuxt/typescript/issues/49
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["server/*"],
      "@/*": [
        "client/*"
      ],
    },
    "types": [
      "node",
      "@types/node",
      "@nuxt/vue-app",
      "vuex-class-component/dist",
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "server/**/*",
    "client/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

my webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const WebpackShellPlugin = require('webpack-shell-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: ['webpack/hot/poll?1000', './server/main.ts'],
  watch: true,
  target: 'node',
  externals: [
    nodeExternals({
      allowlist: ['webpack/hot/poll?1000'],
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  mode: 'development',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new WebpackShellPlugin({ onBuildEnd: ['node dist/main.js'] }),
  ],
  output: {
    path: `${__dirname}/dist`,
    publicPath: '/',
  },
};
```

Command I am running
`ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register server/main.ts`

Comment: What you've posted looks correct. Your issue is elsewhere.

Comment: Hmm. Not sure. I have added more details of tsconfig webpack config and how I am running.

Comment: To be clear, Typescript thinks everything is fine, but it's `undefined` at runtime?

Comment: Yeah. Vs code also navigates fine to that static property. Something runtime or compile issue is happening.

Comment: Got the issue. It was due to other code. cyclic import was happening. Will post the answer .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I didn't post entire code as I thought it wasn't necessary.

But service was also calling back the class where service was imported.

```
import { AuthConfig } from '../config/auth-config';
export class ApiService {
  static apiHost = '/';

  static mgr = new Oidc.UserManager(
    new AuthConfig().IdentityServerOAuth2Config, // This was causing issue as it was causing cyclic imports.
  );
}
```

Follwing is the code where cyclic dependency was happening.

```
import ApiService from '../services/api-service';
export class AuthConfig {
   `${ApiService.apiHost}api/callback` // This was again calling back the apiService resulting in cyclic dependency.
}
```